# Azure DevOps Boards - display query result on a board

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions, azure-boards

how to develop the extension to display query result on a board? Such thing is not possible in the Azure Devops unfortunatelly. I've found two extensions on the marketplace which are doing what I need:

1. [AA Query Board](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=almost-antarctic.aa-query-board&targetId=a522f7a8-0ee1-4696-8456-f882211759df&utm_source=vstsproduct&utm_medium=ExtHubManageList)
2. [Query based boards](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=realdolmen.querybasedboards&targetId=a522f7a8-0ee1-4696-8456-f882211759df&utm_source=vstsproduct&utm_medium=ExtHubManageList)

but this extensions are not updated for a long time and I couldn't contact the authors (I need to change few things in order to be able to use it internally in my company).

I've found also this topic [Add tabs on query result pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/add-query-result-tabs?view=azure-devops), so it looks like it's quite easy to add new tab to the query result menu, but I have no idea and I can't find any info how to get data (work items) from query result to display them?

Rest of the extension is just to display this data in grid, so that would be also quite easy, but getting this query result data is blocking me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I managed to contact the author of the "AA Query Board" extension and it turns out that he has a public repository on GitHub with the source code of the extension, so basically everyone can lookup how it's done or base on it.

Link to the repository: https://github.com/staticnz/aa_query_board

Answer (score 1):

There is a **[Query Results](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/dashboards/widget-catalog?view=azure-devops#query-results-widget)** Widget that you can use to display the query results on the **Dashboards** under **Overview**.

1, First you need to create a shared query if not exist, and save query to the shared queries folder shown as below screenshot. (You can click the **Column options** from the **Editor** page to add and remove columns to be shown on the results)

Or drag and drop the query from **My Queries** folder to **Shared Queries** folder.

[image]

2,  Go to **Dashboards** under **Overview**, and Click **Edit**, then search and add widget **Query results**

[image]

3, Click the **gear icon** on the Query Results widget to configure it and select the query you want to display. Then the query result will be display on the Dashboards

[image]

> Update:

There are some other ways to show the query results on the dashboards, For below example:

- you can select your shared query and click **more actions(3dots)** and click **Add to dashboards**. This will display simple total number of query results.

[image]

- you can also create different **Charts** for the query results and add it to Dashboards.

Select your **shared query** and go to **Charts** tab, the choose **New Chart**, select a **Chart type**,  After you configured the chart, you can click the **3dots** on the chart and add it to **dashboards**, check below screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response, I wasn't aware of this feature :) Unfortunatelly that is not what I'm looking for. I want to simply display query not as a list but as board.

Comment: Hi @AdrianBystrek i updated above answer with some other ways to display a query result, please check it out.